# Pass a function a variable while assigning it a value in the function argument? Example: myFunction( arr, newArr = [] )

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, default-parameters

I'm trying to understand what happens when a variable gets assigned a value inside a function's argument list.

For example: `myFunction(arr, newArr = [])`

Does this mean I'm initializing newArr within the function declaration?

What if I `newArr.push(something)` and then call myFunction again with the new `newArr`, would it reinitialize with a value of `[]` or does that only happen the first time?

It's more of a theoretical question, but here's some example code:

```
function capitalizeFirst(arr, newArr=[]) {
  if(arr.length === 0) {
    return newArr;
  }
  newArr.push(arr[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[0].slice(1));
  return capitalizeFirst(arr.slice(1), newArr);
};
```

Comment: This is a default value if the parameter isn't provided. `return capitalizeFirst(arr.slice(1), newArr);` won't initialize `newArr = []` in the recursive call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **default argument** will only be used when the parameter's value is `undefined` -

```js
function foo(a = [])
{ if (a.length >= 5) return a
  a.push(a.length)
  return foo(a)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo()))        // `a` is undefined
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo([9,9,9]))) // `a` is [9,9,9]
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo()))        // `a` is undefined
console.log(foo() === foo())              // `a` is not shared between calls
```

```js
[0,1,2,3,4]
[9,9,9,3,4]
[0,1,2,3,4]
false
```